# How do I identify if my time series' seasonality is additive or multiplicative?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, exponential-smoothing

The "ExponentialSmoothing" function in Python's "statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters" library gives you the option to set `trend` equal to `additive` or `multiplicative` but it also lets you set a `seasonal` parameter equal to `additive` or `multiplicative`. I believe the `trend` is additive when the peaks & troughs of the time series remain roughly the same. Is this correct? How do I determine if the seasonal parameter is additive or multiplicative?

Here is my time series plotted along with its decomposed plots:

[image: Plots]

Comment: You can see the explanation in this video: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3N9eeOlCrP5cK0QRQxeJd6GrQvhAtpBK Hope it helps. Regards,